# is application.default.properties file will be picked ever?

Tags: java, spring-boot

We have following properties files in our springboot project.

```
application-local.yaml
application-develop.yaml
application-qa.yaml
application-uat.yaml
application-prod.yaml
application-default.yaml
application.yaml
```

From our code i understand that we have one properties file for each envirnonment.
But here my question is "application-default.properties/yaml" file will exeucte by any chance?
will this file executes only when we call **-Dspring.profiles.active=default**
or is there any case where this file will be executed?

Answer (score 6):

The Environment has a set of default profiles (by default, [default]) that are used if no active profiles are set. In other words, if no profiles are explicitly activated, then properties from `application-default` are considered.

See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html)

Comment: Can you clarify whether the `application.yml` is also read if only the default profile is active?

Answer (score 1):

No the default application properties will be "application.yml" If you don't specify any profile. The name of your file "application.default.yml" is confusing yourself.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html